# How to use Web.Contents in PowerQuery with headers and body?

Tags: json, python-requests, dax, powerquery

I need to get data from an API but it is a 2 step process. I need to pass headers and metrics (i.e days, gameTitle etc) as body to get a "ReportID" to then store it in a variable to use it to then request the main report.

So in python, I can do something like this but can't translate it to Power Query:

```
from time import sleep
from requests import request
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import json
import pandas as pd

token = myapikey


payload = {
        "startDate": 1672520400,
        "endDate": 1675198800,
        "dimensions" : ["day", "gameTitle],
        "metrics" : ["revenue"]
    }

url = f"https://api.myapi.com/v1/report/supply"

r = request(
    method='post',
    url=url,
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(payload)
)

headers = {
    "Api-Key":token,
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }

def send_request(payload,token):
    r = request(
        method='post',
        url=url,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(payload)
        )
    return r

resp = send_request(payload=payload,key=token)
report_id = resp.json()['data']['reportId']

def get_report(report_id,key):
    url=f"https://api.myapi.com/v1/report/supply?reportId={report_id}&responseType=result"
    r = request(
        method='get',
        url=url,
        headers=headers
        )
    return r.json()['data']['rows']

rows = get_report(report_id=report_id,key=token)
```

I need to unpack the first response and store the reportID in a variable to then use it in the second request but couldn't found a way to even send the body(payload) in the first place.

Comment: see if this helps https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

Comment: thanks but it doesn't answer my question